# No such module 'SomeModule' after liking plugin to Capacitor app

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I cannot seem to find a real solution for my problem anywhere.. After following the Capacitor documentation and creating successfully an app as well as a plugin, i've linked them both using the following commands:

in plugin directory:

```
-npm run build
-npm link
```

in app's directory:

```
-npm link plugin-name
-npm install
-npx cap sync
```

I open the app's workspace and want to run it on my device *but* instead I am getting an error in the added plugin of the app, that a certain library I'm using in it does not exist.

p.s
Plugin builds normally and has no issues. This occurs only after I'm linking both plugin and app. Am I doing something wrong?

The error I'm getting *inside* the plugin's file.
[image: That's the error I'm getting in the file of the plugin.]
Those are the frameworks linked to the capacitor app.

[image: That's the frameworks linked to the capacitor app.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of this moment I have solved the issue I had. Shamefully there aren't really any precise documentation regarding the subject so I'll try to answer as best I can:

My issue got resolved when I updated the `dependencies` inside the .podspec file inside my plugin's folder.

The specific package I wish to use with the plugin, should be specified inside the `.podspec` file i.e. :
`s.dependency 'PicUPSDKv3'` should be added.

After running `-npx cap sync` on my main project's folder, all pods were initialized correctly and I was able to build and run the project alongside the plugin without any errors.

Comment: Yes, thank you! Adding `s.dependency 'ThirdPartyLib'` to the .podspec of my plugin also solved it.  Afterwards, I also found a hint in the [docs](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/plugins/ios#advanced-configuration).

Answer (score 0):

Running `npm install` unlinks whatever is linked.

You should change the order, first `npm install` and then `npm link plugin-name`.

But it's better if instead of linking the plugin you install it from its local folder.

Comment: I understand what you'r saying but this is the order I saw in various tutorial websites such as: https://eliteionic.com/tutorials/how-to-launch-native-views-in-an-ionic-application/#5-making-the-plugin-available-to-an-application

In any case, this hasn't solved my issue.